# TLS 1.2 implementation in Play Framework 2.3.x with Nginx

Tags: ssl, nginx, playframework, implementation

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.1/ConfiguringHttps describes, in detail, how to implement SSL in Play Framework 2.3.x

However, I am wondering how to implement `TLS 1.2` in Play Framework, do I also need something like Nginx?

I am fairly new to this subject. https://luxsci.com/blog/ssl-versus-tls-whats-the-difference.html shows us that `SSL` is older than `TLS`. I have heard that `SSL` is not secure any more, that's why I ask this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nginx support `TLS 1.2` without problems (check parameter "ssl_protocols"). Forget about `SSL v2` and `SSL v3`, it is not secure, but most browsers support `TLS v1.2`, `TLSv1.1` and `TLS v1`.

You can use Nginx as proxy, and configure HTTPS on nginx. Nginx has many usefull options, it can fast serving static files and proxying all other request to "play" application (to TCP port or to socket).

In your link there is information that you can run Play with HTTPS, so there is no need to use nginx, but I agreee with this part:

> (..) using a reverse proxy in front of Play will give better control
>   and security of HTTPS.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So, https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.1/ConfiguringHttps will also work with `TLS 1.2` (out of the box)?

Comment: @TimVisser Yes. I see that when you use https Play application need JDK 1.8, and JDK 1.8 support TLS 1.2 (http://blog.ivanristic.com/2014/03/ssl-tls-improvements-in-java-8.html). You can allways run application and check it in in browser - most browsers try to use the stronges protocol (TLSv1.2, if not then TLSv1.1 etc).